# Formatting a moment object within a React component

Tags: reactjs, momentjs

I have a set of date/time strings that I am trying to store as `moment` objects in the state tree for my React application. I then am trying to display these objects, formatted, in my component, like so:

`{ ticket.reportDateUtc.format('YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm a') }`

This results in the following error when I try to view this component in my React application:

```
TypeError: ({_isAMomentObject:true, _i:"2015-10-05T20:06:58Z", 
                _f:"YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ssZ", _tzm:-0, _isUTC:false, 
                _pf:{empty:false, unusedTokens:[], unusedInput:[], overflow:-1, charsLeftOver:0, nullInput:false, invalidMonth:null, invalidFormat:false, userInvalidated:false, iso:true},
                _locale:{_ordinalParse:/\d{1,2}(th|st|nd|rd)/, ordinal:(function (number) {
"use strict";
var b = number % 10,
    output = (toInt(number % 100 / 10) === 1) ? 'th' :
    (b === 1) ? 'st' :
    (b === 2) ? 'nd' :
    (b === 3) ? 'rd' : 'th';
return number + output;
}), _abbr:"en", _ordinalParseLenient:/\d{1,2}(th|st|nd|rd)|\d{1,2}/}, _d:(new Date(1444075618000))}) is not extensible
```

However, if I format the `moment` to a string when saving it to the state, then display that string in the component, it displays successfully (but I would prefer not to do this so I can reuse the object with different format options). The [react docs](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/displaying-data.html) seem to indicate I'm using the correct syntax (their example is exactly the same, but using Javascript's built-in `Date` object). Is there something I'm doing wrong, or does the moment library just not work correctly in React components?

Edit: Here is one of the render methods where the problem is manifesting:

```
render() {
    const ticket = this.props.ticket;
    const notes = ticket.notes.map(note => <TicketRowNote key={note.id} note={note}/>);
    return (
        <tr className="pointer" onClick={history.replaceState.bind(this, null, `/tickets/${ticket.id}`)}>
            <td>{ ticket.id }</td>
            <td>
                <i className="fa fa-flag"/>
            </td>
            <td className="text-right no-break">{ ticket.reportDateUtc.format('YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm a') }</td>
            <td className="text-right no-break">{ ticket.lastUpdated.format('YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm a') }</td>
            <td className="text-center">{ ticket.problemtype.detailDisplayName }</td>
            <td>
                <OverlayTrigger trigger={ ["hover", "focus"] } placement="bottom"
                                overlay={<Popover id={ "detail-" + ticket.id + "-popover" } title={ ticket.subject }><span dangerouslySetInnerHTML={ helpers.getMarkup(ticket.detail) }/></Popover>}>
                    <div className="detail-wrapper">
                        <strong>{ ticket.subject }</strong>
                    </div>
                </OverlayTrigger>
            </td>
            <td>
                { notes }
            </td>
            <td className="no-break"><a href={ "mailto:" + ticket.clientReporter.email }><i
                className="fa fa-envelope-o"/></a>&nbsp;{ ticket.displayClient }
            </td>
            <td className="text-center">{ ticket.statustype.statusTypeName }</td>
            <td className="text-center no-break">{ ticket.prioritytype.priorityTypeName }</td>
            <td className="no-break"><a href={ "mailto:" + ticket.clientTech.email }><i
                className="fa fa-envelope-o"/></a>&nbsp;{ ticket.clientTech.displayName }
            </td>
        </tr>
    );
}
```

And the method where the state is updated (I know this looks terrible, unfortunately I'm dealing with a terrible API):

```
export function retrieveTickets(scope) {
    tree.set('isLoading', true);
    api.getTickets(scope).then((res) => {
        let tickets = [];
        // Extremely annoying workaround for WHD being terrible
        let count = res.length;
        res.forEach(function (ticket) {
            api.getTicketDetail(ticket.id).then((res) => {
                for (let attr in res) {
                    if (res.hasOwnProperty(attr)) {
                        ticket[attr] = res[attr];
                    }
                }
                ticket.lastUpdated = moment(ticket.lastUpdated).add(4, 'hours');
                ticket.notes = slice(ticket.notes, 0, 2).map(function (note) {
                    note.commenterName = helpers.extractCommenterName(note.prettyUpdatedString);
                    note.strippedText = helpers.stripTags(note.mobileNoteText);
                    return note;
                });
                ticket.reportDateUtc = moment(ticket.reportDateUtc);
                if (ticket.closeDate) {
                    ticket.closeDate = moment(ticket.closeDate).add(4, 'hours');
                }
                if (ticket.displayDueDate) {
                    ticket.displayDueDate = moment(ticket.displayDueDate).add(4, 'hours');
                }
                tickets.push(ticket);

                if (tickets.length === count) {
                    tree.set('tickets', tickets);
                    tree.set('isLoading', false);
                }
            });
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: Is this `{ ticket.reportDateUtc.format('YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm a') }` what you call in your JSX to display the date?

Comment: Yes, where `ticket.reportDateUtc` is the moment object.

Comment: Then just make sure `ticket.reportDateUtc.format('YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm a')` is a string.

Comment: It is. If I do `console.log(typeof ticket.reportDateUtc.format('YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm a'));` then the console outputs "string". However this uncovered a new strange behavior. If I add `console.log(typeof ticket.reportDateUtc.format('YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm a'));` into the method where I update my state, my view now works. But if I remove that line from my state controller and add it at the top of my component render method instead, it goes back to not working with the same "is not extensible" message.

Comment: Can you show some of your render method?  And also the method where you update your state?  Also Is `ticket` a plain object?  Is `reportDateUtc` a simple property on that object, or is it a property accessor?

Comment: Yes, `ticket` is a plain object and `reportDateUtc` is a property (not an accessor). I've added the render method to the original post, since it was too large to fit into a comment.

Comment: Also, I'm using [baobab](https://github.com/Yomguithereal/baobab) for keeping the state. Is it possible it could be related to that library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your issue is that `baobab` freezes objects given to it, and `moment` objects modify themselves when you call `format`.

Try configuring baobab and setting `immutable` to false and see if that fixes the problem.

Comment: That was it. I should've suspected that earlier, but the error message gave very little direction. Thanks for the help!